# Django with Google App Engine - Tutorial Resources

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I know there have been a lot of questions of this, however those were either few years ago or did not really answer my specific question.

Main:1 - Anyone has any good recommendation, given the following of my needs:

1. I don't want to use any technology that is restricted within the App Engine infrastructure (e.g I know Google App Engine provides their framework too)
2. Some tutorial resources where it assumes that the person doesn't know App Engine and Django but with Python basics.

Main:2 - My second main question is that, does Django serves as one of the best web frameworks for hosting under Google App Engine?

I would appreciate anyone who's willing to share your knowledge on this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are unmeetable. Whatever framework you use, you are stuck with the fact that GAE uses Google's proprietary non-relational db. You can use Django along with Django-nonrel to paper over some of the differences, but they'll always be there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw, I believe Pinax can be used along, just want to confirm with you since I believe you have great knowledge in Django. :) So, is that so, that Pinax can be used for GAE?